# nesting and breaking for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I want to search for keywords in a input that I have asked the user and if the keywords are in the input I want my code to open specific text file (I am using cakes as an example. But if none of the keywords are found I want it to ask the question again.

However I am having trouble ending the loop as it keeps on asking the question. I have tried to keep my code to a minimum but I can always post more if requited.

```
keywords1 = ['jam', 'victoria', 'sponge', 'recipe', 'ingredients']
keywords2 = ['chocolate', 'cake']
keywords3 = ['tiramisu']

def test1():
    global keywords1, keywords2, keywords3, query

    for i in keywords1:
        if i in query:
            f=open('Victoria.txt','r')
            f.read = f.read()
            for i in range(0,1):
                print(f.read)
            f.close()

    for i in keywords1:
        if i not in query:
            question1()
        break

def question1():
    global query
    query = input("\nWhat ingredients do you want?\nmake sure to include the keywords\n")
    test1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    question1()
```

I then want to this again for `n` amount of times as it works with only one loop, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this example code works as you intend. The line `f.read = f.read()` does essentially nothing. It is reassigning the `read()` method of the `f` instance back to `read()`. Basically, you are doing `x = x`. I believe you mean to store the result of the `f.read()` call into a variable to be printed in the following `for` loop, but even that loop is confusing as you only manage to call `print` one time on what will be a reference to the `read` method of the file handle instance. Also, reusing your `i` value in nested iterators is bad practice in general.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance so do you have any suggestion to what it should look like?

Comment: Just for instance, I'd write it more like `for word in keywords1:
    if word in query:
        with open('Victoria.txt','r') as f: 
            print(f.read())` as the `with` statement takes care of some basic file opening stuff for you. It's the kind of stuff you'll learn with more Python exposure, but your approach isn't 'wrong'.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question right, you want something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 5
    for _ in range(0, n+1):  # Loop is called n times
        question1()
```

Or do you mean this part of code:

```
for i in keywords1:
    if i in query:
        f=open('Victoria.txt','r')
        f.read = f.read()
        for i in range(0,1):
            print(f.read)
        f.close()

for i in keywords1:
    if i not in query:
        question1()
    break
```

It can be done as:

```
for i in keywords1:
    if i in query:
        f=open('Victoria.txt','r')
        f.read = f.read()
        for i in range(0,1):
            print(f.read)
        f.close()
    else:
        question1()
    break
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is very helpful in making the code shorter but when I add more code like the one you suggested it keeps on asking in the question. Also it doesn't recognize the keywords in the next bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call question only once

```
should_ask = true
for i in keywords1:
    if i in query:
        should_ask = false
if should_ask:
    question1()
```

Of course you can integrate this code in the first loop

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you should ask question only if none of keywords was found, but you ask it for each keyword which is not present in query. I think you need something like this:

```
def test1():
    if any(keyword in query for keyword in keywords1):
        with open('Victoria.txt','r') as f:
            f_read = f.read()
            for _ in range(0, 1):
                print(f_read)
    else:
        question1()
```